# Is there any way of logging into the Facebook, Google Apps via Jenkins using Cypress or Selenium?

Tags: selenium, facebook, jenkins, automated-tests, cypress

I was trying to create a script in **Selenium** and also in **Cypress** to try to **log into the** **Facebook** or **Googe** **Apps** but once I try to do that I am getting the **errors** that I am using **automation software and bye-bye** in short...

**Selenium:**
I did manage to do the log into the Facebook via sikuli images, but sikuli does not work in Jenkins..

**Cypress:**
I have found https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-social-logins this plugin, but it's more about login with Facebook, ... not logging directly into the google apps.

Do you know any way of **how to successfully log in to any big social platform via Jenkins**?

**Thank you** in advance!

Comment: Jenkins – an open source automation server which enables developers around the world to reliably build, test, and deploy their software. You need one binding language to do what you are trying to do, Selenium can be used. I don't think that Sikuli us required

Comment: also, you have to bypass detection since google blocks bot traffic for obvious reasons.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to programmetically interact with them except if you use the API.

Comment: I guess Sikulix is not mad after Jenkins; it's just a bit tricky to configure Sikulix's headless mode

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys, I was just wondering if somebody knows some kind of workaround :-) I wanted to automate primarily google drive apps so that's why I asked :-) thank you again!